# AOC monitor times out after a few seconds to minutes

Tags: monitor-settings

My AOC monitor is hooked up to a DVR Video camera surveillance system.

The monitor continues to timeout or go 'black' every few minutes, sometimes after a few seconds. The power button is "ON" and blue, but the screen is black.

I have changed out the D-SUB cable, turned the monitor on and off and still no luck.  I adjusted the timeout to 120, but I don't know if that is minutes or seconds- either way it is not consistent!

What can I do?